# Why does jQuery Datepicker select today's date when numbers are entered and enter is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have discovered a scenario in an app I'm working on that is replicated on the jQuery site. For example, if you go [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and enter a string of integers (e.g. "12345678") and hit enter, you'll see that the current date then fills the input. If you then retype another string of numbers and hit enter again, your typed string remains.

In my application I need whatever numbers are typed to remain after ANY enter key press. My questions are:

1. Why is the string overwritten with a date on the initial enter key press event?
2. How can this behaviour be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Enter key will always grab the selected date and output this value to the textbox.  This selected date will be the default date when it is opened.  You can set the defaultDate when opening the datepicker, but it will either be a valid date or today's date.  There is no way currently to open a datepicker with no defaultDate out of the box.

Normally, you can remove the selected date by setting it to null.

```
$('#mydate').datepicker('setDate', null);
```

But this won't work when the datepicker is initially opened, since it ALWAYS opens with a default/selected date.

I've come up with [a fiddle showing a possible work around](http://jsfiddle.net/JcY4P/2/).

```
/***
    Since there is ALWAYS a default date in the datepicker when it's opened,
    then let's try and trigger an event after it has been opened, then set the
    date to null.
***/
$('#textbox').datepicker(
{
    beforeShow: function() 
    {
        $(this).trigger('afterShow');        
    }
})
.bind('afterShow', function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      $this.datepicker('setDate', null);  
    }, 100); 
});
```